# Declare Sails JS responses as classes

Tags: javascript, sails.js, commonjs

I'd like to declare some responses as javascript classes, given that I have some common behavior between them. Is this posible? In Sail's documentation I see that they're always declared as functions:

> module.exports = function (data) {
>       // Some common functionality
>       return res.jsonx(data);
>   };

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of v1.0, all Sails apps come with built-in support for helpers, simple utilities that let you share Node.js code in more than one place. This helps you avoid repeating yourself, and makes development more efficient by reducing bugs and minimizing rewrites. Like actions2, this also makes it much easier to create documentation for your app.

For example, in the course of creating the actions that your Node.js/Sails app uses to respond to client requests, you will sometimes find yourself repeating code in several places. That can be pretty bug-prone, of course, not to mention annoying. Fortunately, there's a neat solution: replace the duplicate code with a call to a custom helper

[find more about sails helpers](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers)